# get_permalink to attachment not working

Tags: permalinks, attachments

I have following code

```
    <?php

      $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'attachment',
   'numberposts' => 12,
   'post_status' => null
  );

  $attachments = get_posts( $args );
     if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
           echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink( $attachment->ID ).'">';
           echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, array('100', '100') );
          echo '</a></li>';
          }
     }

?>
```

The point of this script is to show last added 12 photos (thumbs of it). And this works perfect. But I want to add second funcionality - link to the page where it comes from (usually native gallery embed into post/page)

The problem is that in this case the link is corrupted. It always links to the very first post. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is that you query for Post Status `null`. Try setting this to `publish` or `inherit`, because `get_permalink` is a function for published items, not for any post status.

This is because Permalinks to items with a status like `draft` should not be shown to the user.

Comment: THX fischi. I've found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Final version

```
<?php

      $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'attachment',
   'numberposts' => 12,
   'post_status' => null
  );

  $attachments = get_posts( $args );
     if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
           $url = get_permalink( $attachment->ID );
          echo '<li><a href="'.strstr($url, '/attachment', true).'">';
           echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, array('100', '100') );
          echo '</a></li>';       
          }
     }

?>
```

where /attachment is everything NOT needed in the URL.